# What should I return if my cacheResolver found no cache to use?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I'm using EhCache on a service's delegate with spring's annotations.

On my `@Cacheable` annotation I've added a `resolverFactoryName` field to resolve my cache at runtime.

Then I implement `CacheableCacheResolver` interface, and return a cache depending of business rules, but sometimes I have no cache to return according to these rules.

If I return null EhCache's lib gave me a NPE. **What is the way to do when I've no cache to return and so the app should no cache any of these values ?** Is there a "fake" cache to return? Is there something like a NoCacheException to throw?

Comment: What about returning a cache with the capacity of 0 entries?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think exception is the way to go, you really want to return a no-op cache implementation.

From the class name you give - `CacheableCacheResolver` - it looks like you are using `ehcache-spring-annotations` which does not seem to have support for what you want - a no-op cache.

Note that you can still take care of it yourself.

If you were to use the Spring Caching abstraction, you could use a [similar system](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-jsr-107-summary) which has support for no-op caches through `org.springframework.cache.support.NoOpCacheManager.NoOpCache`.